# jquery color works for text not div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a simple color picker using jQuery:
JS:

```
$(function(){
 $("#color-input").keyup(function(){
  var colorCode = $(this).html();
  $(this).css('color', colorCode);
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="color-input" id="color-input">
```

It is supposed to read the input of the textbox, and make it the text the inputted color. This works, but when I tried doing this:

```
<input type="text" name="color-input" id="color-input">
<div id="color-box" style="height:250px; width:250px;"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
      $("#color-input").keyup(function(){
         var colorCode = $(this).html();
         $(this).css('color', colorCode);
         $("#color-box").css('background', colorCode);
      });
    });
```

it only works for certain colors, like `#FF00FF` or `rgb(0,255,0)`. For codes like this: `#7f154`, the text changes color, and not the div. How can I make both match the inputted color no matter the code? [**LIVE PAGE**](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com/c/snippets/color_picker)

Comment: I believe you should be using `$(this).val()` instead of `$(this).html()`

Comment: Also try background-color instead of background? It may be complaining about the improperly formatted hex color. #7f154 is not a complete RGB color since it is missing 1 digit

Comment: `input` is void element, it doesn't have any content so `html()` fails. You want the value of the input. As a side note, you should use `$("#color-input").on('input', handler);` to handle cases where user copy/paste/drag value into input

Comment: #7f154 is not a valid hex color

Comment: and you should do a color validity check before setting it as color and background, otherwise you may have unexpected results. Do a regex to check them.

Comment: @A.Wolff, I meant to write `.val()` Thanks for pointing that out though

Comment: @Reflective, the code worked for me. True it isn't quite valid, but it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change 'background-color' property, not 'background':

```
$(function(){
      $("#color-input").keyup(function(){
         var colorCode = $(this).val();
         $(this).css('color', colorCode);
         $(this).css('background', 'none');
         $("#readout").css('background-color', colorCode); //changed to background-color
         $("#readout-t").val(colorCode);
      });
    });
```

Also if user will put value you should check if it begins with '#':

```
$(function(){
      $("#color-input").keyup(function(){
         var colorCode = $(this).val();
         $(this).css('color', colorCode);
         $(this).css('background', 'none');
         //check if valid color
         if (colorCode.charAt(0) != '#') {
              colorCode = '#' + colorCode;
         }
         $("#readout").css('background-color', colorCode);
         $("#readout-t").val(colorCode);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Although if users will be entering `rgb` and `rgba` codes, checking to see if the code starts with `#` is pretty useless.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in your jquery.. You have used `$(this).html()` but is should be `$(this).val()`.

```
$(function(){
      $("#color-input").keyup(function(){
         var colorCode = $(this).val();
         $(this).css('color', colorCode);
         $("#color-box").css('background', colorCode);
      });
    });
```